# Is it possible to trigger an event to happen when location permission is denied in javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, permissions, geolocation

**Context:** A follow up question to my question about getCurrentPosition and async functions. Working through the Odin Project and trying to build a simple weather app, I would like to implement a feature where the app automatically populates the app with the user's local weather using the `navigator.geolocation` feature.

**What I expect:** The user clicks 'block', and the `loadApp` if-statement runs and defaults to a hard-coded coordinate (Kansas lol). If the user clicks 'allow', their lat/lon location is grabbed and the page can make its initial api request for the user's local weather.

**What happens instead:** The user clicks 'block', and the whole code stops. Just, doesn't go anywhere. I don't know how to get it back to continue to the if-statement in `loadApp`. (Clicking allow works just fine and I am able to successfully get coordinates when I test on my home machine)

**What I have tried:** Googled the issue and tried writing a function that queries the status of the global permission object. I thought maybe I could break out of it if I could find *anywhere* where permission was denied, but no matter where examine, the status is simply 'prompted'. I also tried to use the `reject` statement in my promise, but that only runs if the user has no geolocation at all.

```
function getLocationFromUser (){
    //promisify the callback by wrapping it in a promise and return the promise immediately
    //wrapping things in a promise is a way to return from a callback
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            let defaultCoords = [];
            defaultCoords.push(position.coords.latitude);
            defaultCoords.push(position.coords.longitude);
            //this resolve statement is what is actually returned by the promise
            resolve((defaultCoords));
        });
      } else {
        reject(console.log('Geolocation not supported'));
      }
    });
  }


async function loadApp(){
    let defaultLocation = await getLocationFromUser();
    
    if(!defaultLocation){
        alert('user denied us');
        //load a default city
        getWeatherData(37.9795, 23.7162);
        
    } else {
        console.log(defaultLocation);
        let lat = defaultLocation[0];
        let lon = defaultLocation[1];
        getWeatherData(lat, lon);
    }
}

function getWeatherData(lat, lon){
    //this is where my API call will run using the lat and lon data

}

loadApp().then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API/Using_the_Geolocation_API.

```
if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            let defaultCoords = [];
            defaultCoords.push(position.coords.latitude);
            defaultCoords.push(position.coords.longitude);
            //this resolve statement is what is actually returned by the promise
            resolve((defaultCoords));
        }, 
        // When the permission is denied
        () => {
            // Add the longitudes and latitudes of the hard-coded coordinate here
            const longitude = 0;
            const latitude = 0;
            resolve([latitude, longitude])
        );
      } else {
        reject(console.log('Geolocation not supported'));
      }
```

According to Mozilla Geolocation API, the function `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error)` takes the two parameters. The first parameter has the function that is ran during the successful retrieval of the location, which you already encoded. The second paramater has the function that is run when the user rejects your request, which I have encoded in where the comment says "Permission is denied". For the function to work, change both the values of longitude and latitude to the desired hardcoded coords and it should work.